# Is it possible to output all of the EC2 instances that are created in a loop with Terraform?

Tags: terraform

I am creating many nodes with Terraform loops like the following:

```
resource "aws_instance" "dev-cluster" {
  ami                  = "${lookup(var.amis, var.region)}"
  instance_type        = "${var.instance_type}"
  count                = 13
  subnet_id            = "${var.global-private-subnet-1a-id}"
}
```

Is there a way to output all of these instance ids somehow in the outputs.tf?

I was trying but the output is empty

```
output "aws_ec2_instance_ids" {
  value = "${aws_instance.dev-cluster.*.id}"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `aws_instance.dev-cluster.*.id` returns multiple values, the output is an array and it must be inside brackets:

```
output "aws_ec2_instance_ids" {
  value = ["${aws_instance.dev-cluster.*.id}"]
}
```